# Использование неинициализированного значения

Tags: perl

```
 ###!usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $info_by_params;
$info_by_params =  [       {
        'count' => '1',
        'status' => 0,
        'cn' => 'vt',
        'sn' => '9999',
        'route' => 'hu',
        'mccmnc' => undef
  } ];
my $ret_data;
foreach my $data ( @$info_by_params  ){
   $ret_data->{$data->{route}}{$data->{cn}}{$data->{mccmnc}}{$data->{sn}} {count_undelivered} += $data->{count};
}
print Dumper $ret_data;
```

> Use of uninitialized value in hash
> element at.

Как быть с использованием неинициализированного значения?

Comment: У Вас форматирование слетело... Поправьте, пожалуйста, если не сложно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала решить, можно ли использовать "пустое" значение из списка, если нет - делать проверку:

```
if (defined $data->{route} && defined $data->{cn} && defined $data->{mccmnc} && defined $data->{sn}) {
    ...
}
```

Если все-таки можно, то либо добавить прагму

```
foreach ... {
    no warnings;
    ...
}
```

либо подставлять пустое значение, если оно не объявлено:

```
$data->{mccmnc} ||= "";
```

Answer (score 1):

При попытке взять элемент {undef} из хеша берётся элемент {''} и выдаётся вот этот ворнинг. Простейший способ этого избежать - использовать defined-or: $foo{ $bar // "bar was not defined" }. Это если perl >= 5.10.

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;

 my %foo; 
 my $bar;
 $foo{$bar}++; # warning
 $foo{$bar || 0}++; # no warning
 $foo{$bar // "no bar"}++; # no warning, perl 5.10+ only
```

В данном случае отсутствует mccnmc. Но вообще в теории любой параметр в $data может ВНЕЗАПНО отсутствовать, и надо либо проверять, что он есть, либо заменять на некое разумное значение по умолчанию.